# when concurrent read and write to hbase, the write time doesn't change with the amount of data

Tags: hadoop, hbase, ycsb

I have seven machines acting as slaves, I used four of them to write to hbase and three of them to read from hbase.

However, the four which I use to write to hbase always take constant time:247 minutes when writing 25 million,50 million, 80 million and 100 million data to hbase.

I wonder how did that happen, is it because hbase or my testing way is incorrect.

By the way, I use YCSB 0.1.3 to test my hbase group. The version of hbase is 0.96.1.1 and the version of hadoop is 2.2.0

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!:-)

Comment: Can you share the command you have used to run the tests

Comment: I use 
{
java -cp build/ycsb.jar:db/hbase/lib/*:db/hbase/conf com.yahoo.ycsb.Client -load -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient -P workloads/workloada -p columnfamily=family -p recordcount=1000 -s > load.dat 

}
to load data into hbase and use
{
java -cp build/ycsb.jar:db/hbase/lib/*:db/hbase/conf com.yahoo.ycsb.Client -t -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.HBaseClient -P workloads/workloadc -p columnfamily=a -p operationcount=100000000 -s > transactions.dat} to read from hbase